# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular8

I m passsing ID with routerLink for blog component, Its giving me error - Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'blog/%5B'../blogdetails',%20blogs.post_id%5D'

```
 constructor(private http:HttpClient,private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => console.log(params) );
   }
  <p><a routerLink="['../blogdetails', blogs.post_id]" href="#">{{blogs.post_title}}</a> </p>

{ path: 'blogdetails/:id', component: BlogdetailsComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
```

Comment: Use a `where` clause so you select the rows you want.

Comment: i tried but it's returning the whole tree, when I am logging in as a child then it should return tree of childs but it's returning the whole tree with previous parent_id

Comment: Please update the code in the question. Also show sample database records, and how it should be returned.

Comment: this code is working fine but it returns the tree of users, (user1([use2....][user3][user4][user5])).. but when logged in as user 2 it's returning the same, I wanna know how to get tree for logged in user

Comment: Where/how are you using there `where` clause?

Comment: i tried with where but its not working,